# How do I detect what invoked a jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Apologies for no code. But I don't have a starting point for this question.

I have searched jquery and javascript documentation but I must be using the wrong terms because I am not getting anywhere.

I wish to take action within a jquery script dependant on what invoked the script.

i.e. I have the same jquery script in several php files. I don't want to create a separate script for each php file. I want to know which php file invoked that script and alter it's behaviour accordingly.

It seems like a perfectly reasonable thing to want to do so I am hoping that it is a really easy question.

Comment: You can use console.log("test") to see if its been invoked

Comment: You can pass some parameter to that script/function which would tell where the call happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the `window.location` object - it'll tell you the URL of the containing HTML page.

Comment: As an additional note here for the benefit of others. window.location appears to return an object. To extract a meaningful context suitable for my purposes I needed to get the href property of that object, and break that down to acquire the actual php file like so:                          alert ((window.location.href).split("/").pop()); There may of course  be a more elegant solution but this works for me.

Comment: @codepuppy indeed, that's why I said "object" and not "string".  FWIW, you probably want `.pathname` instead of `.href` - that'll get you the relative path without the hostname or URI scheme on it.

Comment: ok even better. Sorry for misreading your post. But I probably learnt more because of this so that's great.

Answer (score 0):

Let the PHP file echo a config object to tell the JS how to behave (e.g. on what type of page it executes):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    config = <?php
        $config = array("page" => …, "state" => …);
        echo json_encode($config);
    ?>;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/common.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes I can see this also but I will give the window.location a go first.

Comment: Of course this depends on the complexity of your page. If you had some router functionality in PHP you wouldn't need to repeat that in the JS with my solution